# Injecting Generic type parameters with AutoFac

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I think I am really confused about what I can do with AutoFac, can someone please put me on track.

I have a base type

```
class PersonBase{ 
    public string SaySomething(){
       return "I am base";
    }
}
```

I derive two concrete classes

```
class FakePerson : PersonBase{
    public override string SaySomething(){
       return "I'm so Fake";
    }
}

class RealPerson : PersonBase{
    public override string SaySomething(){
       return "I am For Real";
    }
}
```

Create a generic class, PersonHandler, to deal with different types of people and would like the PersonHandler to instantiate the person at the appropriate time, so I do not want an instance of Person injected, just need to derived type

```
class PersonHandler<T>
    where T : PersonBase, new() {

    T _Person;    

    public DoWork(){
        _Person = new T();
        _Person.SaySomething();
    }
}
```

Now I try to use the handler, after registering the types as detailed next, with varying results.

```
var ph = contrainer.Resolve<PersonHandler<PersonBase>>();
ph.DoWork();
```

I attempted to register the types as follows

```
1. vBuilder.RegisterType<PersonHandler<FakePerson>>().As<PersonHandler<PersonBase>>();
```

This gives me an error stating the `PersonHandler<FakePerson>` is not assignable to `PersonHandler<PersonBase>` (or the other way around I don't recal which)

```
2. vBuilder.RegisterGeneric<typeof(PersonHandler<>)>
   vBuilder.RegisterType<FakePerson>().As<PersonBase>();
```

This does not resolve `PersonBase` to `FakePerson`, but just gives `PersonHandler<PersonBase>`, So it results in "I am Base"

```
3. vBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PersonHandler<FakePerson>)).As(typeof(PersonHandler<PersonBase>));
```

This given an error saying that `PersonHandler<FakePerson>` is not an open type

So now I have been chasing my tale all day and, frankly, it is getting quit tedious,

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 10):

The (almost) correct solution is this one that you already tried:

```
builder.RegisterType<PersonHandler<FakePerson>>()
    .As<PersonHandler<PersonBase>>();
```

The reason Autofac gave you an error is that generic class types in C# don't work this way.

That is, you can't write:

```
PersonHandler<PersonBase> ph = new PersonHandler<FakePerson>();
```

(Give it a try in your IDE - the compiler will reject it.)

The reason for this is that contravariance, the required feature added in C#4, only supports interface types.

To cut a long story short, if you create `IPersonHandler<T>` and use that as the service then the above code will work as expected:

```
interface IPersonHandler<in T>
    where T : PersonBase, new() {

    void DoWork();
}
```

Note the `in` parameter on the interface declaration.

Make `PersonHandler<T>` implement `IPersonHandler<T>`:

```
class PersonHandler<T> : IPersonHandler<T>
    where T : PersonBase, new() {
```

Then register like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<PersonHandler<FakePerson>>()
    .As<IPersonHandler<PersonBase>>();
```

You can then get handlers using:

```
IPersonHandler<PersonBase> handler =
    container.Resolve<IPersonHandler<PersonBase>>();
```

The returned `handler` object will be of type `PersonHandler<FakePerson>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you resolve a service that is registered with an open generic type (such as `PersonHandler<>`) you need to specify the exact closed type that you want to handle, and Autofac will generate one for you.

In this case, you called `container.Resolve<PersonHandler<PersonBase>>()` so you were returned a `PersonHandler<PersonBase>`. Now, if you look at your `PersonHandler` class, and substitute `PersonBase` for `T`, the resulting `DoWork` method looks like this:

```
public DoWork(){
    _Person = new PersonBase();
    _Person.SaySomething();
}
```

So the `SaySomething()` call uses the method on the base class.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to decide which concrete `PersonBase` implementation to use during registration. If this is the case, you might try using the [Delegate Factory](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories) feature of Autofac instead:

```
class PersonHandler
{
    private readonly Func<PersonBase> createPerson;

    public PersonHandler(Func<PersonBase> createPerson)
    {
        this.createPerson = createPerson;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        PersonBase pb = this.createPerson();
        Console.WriteLine(pb.SaySomething());
    }
}
```

Then you can register your classes as follows:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<RealPerson>().As<PersonBase>();
builder.RegisterType<PersonHandler>();
var context = builder.Build();
var handler = context.Resolve<PersonHandler>();
handler.DoWork();
```

By varying the second line of this code, you can register whichever type of `PersonBase` you actually want to use in the program.

Comment: It seems to me that Ricardo is trying to make his code testable, but I believe he is heading the wrong way in his design. I must say I'm not a fan of using delegates directly as delegates, because I think it makes your design not explicit enough. Some prominent SO users however, do like using them.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "using delegates directly as delegates ... makes your design not explicit enough." The delegate factory feature of Autofac is a great way to keep IoC container dependencies out of the code base; but I agree that it can be a bit opaque at first. Your solution is an equally effective one - except that I think the line vBuilder.RegisterType<IPersonHandler>().As<PersonHandler<RealPerson>>() should read vBuilder.RegisterType<PersonHandler<RealPerson>>().As<IPersonHandler>();

Comment: Little typo there. What I meant to say was: "use factories directly as delegates". You are right about the bug in my code. Thanks.